# How to use stable_sort to sort the fruit_name (data from file) and print

Tags: c++

I need to create an operator< to use the stable_sort. I want to use the stable_sort to sort for fruit_name from a struct
Here is my operator< (inside a struct):

```
struct fruit_t {
        char fruit_name[MAX_LENGTH];                                            // name of fruit
        float quantity;                                                 // in lbs
        float price;                                                    // price tag of the fruit
        friend bool operator< (const fruit_t& f1, const fruit_t& f2){           //overload operator <
                return (strcmp (f1.fruit_name, f2.fruit_name) < 0);
        }
};
```

I read in the fruit_name by

```
while(true){
inFile >> fruit[i].fruit_name
if(inFile.eof()) break;
i++
}
```

Comment: And what happens when you do that? There is nothing obviously wrong with the code.

Comment: sorry. I want to use the STL stable_sort() to sort the fruit_name. I didn't know the syntax or how to implement it.

Comment: `std;;stable_sort(std::begin(fruit), std::end(fruit));`?

Comment: @AnPhan [Here are all your answers.](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_sort/)

Answer (score 1):

When you have overloaded `operator<` you can just use `std::stable_sort(begin(fruit), end(fruit));`

Instead of overload the operator before (so if you only want to use this kind of comparison once, you can use a lambda expression like this:

```
std::stable_sort(begin(fruit), end(fruit), [](auto const& a, auto const& b){
  return strcmp (a.fruit_name, b.fruit_name) < 0;
});
```

The syntax in the reference (all these iterators) might be confusing you. For now, just use `begin` and `end` and when you get more familiar with the language, you should try to understand iterators.

Comment: was the syntax right?. It gave me the error that begin and end weren't declared. I did include <vector>

Comment: I tried it and it worked. Did you include ```<string.h>``` and ```<algorithm>```? https://godbolt.org/z/Pac63v